# Convert first two bytes of Lua string (in bigendian format) to unsigned short number

Tags: lua

I want to have a lua function that takes a string argument. String has N+2 bytes of data. First two bytes has length in bigendian format, and rest N bytes contain data.

> Say data is "abcd" 
> So the string is 0x00 0x04 a b c d

In Lua function this string is an input argument to me.
How can I calculate length optimal way.

So far I have tried below code

```
function calculate_length(s)
    len = string.len(s)
    if(len >= 2) then
        first_byte = s:byte(1);
        second_byte = s:byte(2);
        //len = ((first_byte & 0xFF) << 8) or (second_byte & 0xFF)
        len = second_byte
    else
        len = 0
    end
    return len
end
```

See the commented line (how I would have done in C).
In Lua how do I achieve the commented line.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I wrote it. For me now first byte comes 0, so I just consider 2nd byte as length and continuing. However I need to write it properly where I need to consider first byte as well.

Comment: Show the code you tried as well. Currently, your question looks like a project dumped

Comment: is the string exactly like "`0x000x04abcd`"?

Comment: Now it is "0x000x04abcd" , but it may come with first byte value when I deal with bigger strings.

Comment: Pass `16` as base to [`tonumber`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-tonumber).

Comment: I tried to put len = tonumber(s, 16) , but gives nil

Comment: Also I tried   str = s:sub(1,2)    len = tonumber(str, 10)    still it does not work

Comment: Looks can not use tonumber

Comment: `len = s:byte(1) * 256 + s:byte(2)`

Comment: `function calculate_length(s)
  return #s < 2 and 0 or s:byte(1) * 256 + s:byte(2)
end`

Comment: http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/struct/ `print( struct.unpack( '>i2c0', '\0\4abcd' ) )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of data bytes in your string `s` is `#s-2` (assuming even a string with no data has a length of two bytes, each with a value of 0).  If you really need to use those header bytes, you could compute:

```
len = first_byte * 256 + second_byte
```

When it comes to strings in Lua, a byte is a byte as [this excerpt about strings](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1) from the Reference Manual makes clear:

> The type *string* represents immutable sequences of bytes. Lua is 8-bit clean: strings can contain any 8-bit value, including embedded zeros ('\0'). Lua is also encoding-agnostic; it makes no assumptions about the contents of a string.

This is important if using the `string.*` library:

> The string library assumes one-byte character encodings.

If the internal representation in Lua of your number is important, the following [excerpt from the Lua Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1) may be of interest:

> The type number uses two internal representations, or two subtypes, one called integer and the other called float. Lua has explicit rules about when each representation is used, but it also converts between them automatically as needed.... Therefore, the programmer may choose to mostly ignore the difference between integers and floats or to assume complete control over the representation of each number. Standard Lua uses 64-bit integers and double-precision (64-bit) floats, but you can also compile Lua so that it uses 32-bit integers and/or single-precision (32-bit) floats.

In other words, the 2 byte "unsigned short" C data type does not exist in Lua. Integers are stored using the "long long" type (8 byte signed).

Lastly, as [lhf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107090/lhf) pointed out in the comments, bitwise operations were added to Lua [in version 5.3](https://www.lua.org/versions.html), and if lhf is *the* lhf, he should know ;-)

Comment: Lua 5.3 has bitwise operators.

Comment: Thanks @lhf.  I added this to my answer.